# Not all entries of .bib file converted to .bbl

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am new to LaTeX. So far I was able to deal with everything by searching the internet. But now I am stuck! I use TeXmaker as an editor.

I have 332 entries in a `.bib` file and which is included in a `main.tex` file. When I compile via `pdflatex`--`bibtex`--`pdflatex`--`pdflatex` I see all in text citation till bib entry number 312! Interestingly enough I get also the very last entry. But all entries between 312 and 331 come with a (?) symbol in the PDF. It turns out that in my `.bbl` file these entries (312-331) are completely missing and I don't get why. The entries appear as they should in the `.aux` file i.e.`\citation{312}`, but I do get error in the `log` file:

```
"Package natbib Warning: Citation `312' on page 38 undefined on input line 136."
```

Please help!

Example from my `.bib` file:

```
@article{311,
   author = {Altschul, S. F. and Gish, W. and Miller, W. and Myers, E. W. and Lipman, D. J.},
   title = {Basic local alignment search tool},
   journal = {J Mol Biol},
   volume = {215},
   number = {3},
   pages = {403-10},
   ISSN = {0022-2836 (Print)
0022-2836 (Linking)},
   DOI = {10.1016/S0022-2836(05)80360-2},
   url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2231712},
   year = {1990},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{312,
   author = {Neri, D. and Szyperski, T. and Otting, G. and Senn, H. and Wuthrich, K.},
   title = {Stereospecific nuclear magnetic resonance assignments of the methyl groups of valine and leucine in the DNA-binding domain of the 434 repressor by biosynthetically directed fractional 13C labeling},
   journal = {Biochemistry},
   volume = {28},
   number = {19},
   pages = {7510-6},
   ISSN = {0006-2960 (Print)
0006-2960 (Linking)},
   url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2692701},
   year = {1989},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

Example from my `.bbl` file:

```
\bibitem[{Altschul et~al.(1990)Altschul, Gish, Miller, Myers, \& Lipman}]{311}
Altschul, S.~F., Gish, W., Miller, W., Myers, E.~W., \& Lipman, D.~J.Basic
  local alignment search tool.
\newblock t.
\newblock {\em J Mol Biol\/}, {\em 215\/}(3), 403--10.
```

MWE from comment:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\begin{document} 
asfd \citep{250} asdf2sdafasdfasdasfdadfs \citep{312} \bibliographystyle{styles/apagood} 
\bibliography{literature1} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post your .bib somewhere, so we can have a look? Also, a usual thing to do when unexpected things happen, is delete .aux and .bbl and recompile from scratch.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @mico i use apagood style. but i test also plain and apalike with no success

Comment: I cant seem to be able to reproduce it!!

i guess the following is my MWE. but its not really reproducing the problem!

`\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
asfd \citep{250}
asdf2sdafasdfasdasfdadfs \citep{312}
\bibliographystyle{styles/apagood}
\bibliography{literature1}
\end{document}`

Comment: I think i fixed it. I deleted .aux & .bbl files and its fine now!! thanks!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because deleting the temp files solves the problem ...